# Regular Expression - SPECIFICWORD_ANYWORD_ANYWORD_SPECIFICLETTER

Tags: regex, oracle

I am developing a solution at my work to check a number of database values in order to see if they match an specific format. I have been developing it using pure PL/SQL, but its getting overcomplicated and I believe that using regex is the simplest and most effective way. The expression that I need to match is:

```
SPECIFICWORD_ANYWORD_ANYWORD_SPECIFICLETTER
```

The first `SPECIFICWORD` is just `APEX`, followed by an underscore (`_`), followed by any word, followed by an underscore (`_`), followed by any word, followed by an underscore (`_`) and then followed by any letter that are included on an specific set (in this case, `D`, `P`, or `E`). Also, every character need to be uppercase.

Can someone help me with this? Or at least recommend me to a guide or similar question that I can discover my answer from.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_regexp.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^APEX_[A-Z0-9]+_[A-Z0-9]+_[DPE]$
```

Comment: Great. Now, since I am using it inside an SQL query, and I want only those results that doesn't match this regex, can I negate this regex? Something like !^APEX_[A-Z0-9]+_[A-Z0-9]+_[DPE]$

Comment: That depends upon what SQL engine is in use. Can you tell me which database are you using and what is your SQL query for regex matching.